# How to do Pagination and Hateoas in JAX-RS/JEE?

Tags: jakarta-ee, pagination, jax-rs, hateoas

Adding Pagination and HATEOAS to a REST-resource in Spring is quite simple and supported out of the box:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pages", method = RequestMethod.GET)
PagedResources<NoteResource> allPaged(@PageableDefault Pageable p, PagedResourcesAssembler<Note> pagedAssembler) {
    Page<Note> pageResult = noteRepository.findAll(p);
    return pagedAssembler.toResource(pageResult, noteResourceAssembler);
}
```

That's it. I can call `localhost:8080/notes/pages?page=0&size=2`and get the following JSON back:

```
{
"_embedded": {
    "noteList": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "firstNote",
            "body": "lala",
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/notes/1"
                },
                "note-tags": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/notes/1/tags"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "secondNote",
            "body": "blabla",
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/notes/2"
                },
                "note-tags": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/notes/2/tags"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
"_links": {
    "first": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/notes/pages?page=0&size=2"
    },
    "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/notes/pages?page=0&size=2"
    },
    "next": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/notes/pages?page=1&size=2"
    },
    "last": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/notes/pages?page=5&size=2"
    }
},
"page": {
    "size": 2,
    "totalElements": 12,
    "totalPages": 6,
    "number": 0
}
```

}

How can I achieve the same with plain JavaEE and JAX-RS?

Comment: I think you have to do it manually. I think you can get inspired here: https://stormpath.com/blog/beautiful-rest-json-apis-jax-rs-and-jersey

Comment: This article can help: [Handling Pagination With JAX-RS and NoSQL in Your Jakarta EE/MicroProfile Application](https://dzone.com/articles/handling-with-pagination-with-jax-rs-in-your-jakar)